# How to check in SELECT statement if column exists before showing it

Tags: ms-access, exists

I use Access 97. In select statement i would like to check if column, which I would like to be shown, exists in my tabe. If it is not it should not be shown in the result, or it can be fil with 0/NULL etc.

The following code in SQL Server looks like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE [name] = N'Minuta' 
                AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'DokFin'))
BEGIN
    SELECT Godzina from DokFin
END
```

but how can I achieve this in MS Access 97?

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't have full system dictionaries like in MS SQL, so you cannot check if column exists using pure SQL. As a workaround you can create VBA function and use it in WHERE clause of your SQL SELECT